# Some commands not working in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, dash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.02 32bit.

On doing some shell programming, I found out that running the script through the sh command sometimes cause errors.

Is it because the sh command is invoking the dash shell instead of #!/bin/bash ?

I'm having trouble with the select command.

It goes well when I execute it by ./scriptName.sh, but sh scriptName.sh reports syntax errors. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, bash has implemented additional commands, and is a superset of sh (or dash). If your script uses bash-specific commands (some call them "bashisms") then you must use bash to execute the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script uses bash syntax, it must start with `#!/bin/bash`. If you execute it with `/path/to/script` then all will be well. If you call the interpreter (the shell) explicitly, then you need to call the correct one, i.e. `bash`, not `sh` or `perl` or whatever.

There are several variants of `sh`. Bash is one. Dash is another. Compared with bash, dash has fewer features but is faster and uses less memory. This is why Ubuntu chose to use dash as `sh`; if you need bash's extra features then n you should call it explicitly anyway.